# How to obtain context in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview and want to open a new activity showing full info about the element clicked.
This is the code i have for setOnItemClickListener, the Toast works fine and showing the element name correctly, but it does not open the new activity and it logs this error: ***W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@dcc4899***

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int pos = recyclerViewFestivales.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
            Festival festivalSeleccionado = listaFestivales.get(pos);
            String nombreFestival = listaFestivales.get(pos).getNombre();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seleccion: " + nombreFestival, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FestivalActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("nombreFestival", nombreFestival);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I read on another article that you can not get context in onCreat, i don't know if the error is there or how can i solve it...

Comment: English please..

Comment: sorry, updated now

Comment: Where does this code live? OnCreate() or OnCreateView()?

Comment: Is the setContentView(R.layout.your_layout) set in onCreate ?

Comment: this code is in OnCreate()

Comment: if `getApplicationContext()` is working for showing the toast have you tried calling it to create your intent? `Intent(getApplicationContext()...)`

Comment: just tried getApplicationContext() instead and got the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

In this case, just specify your Activity name instead of v.getContext(). Like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FromActivity.this, FestivalActivity.class);
```

Comment: that is what i have in the intent and it is not working

Comment: What exactly does the error say? note: you need to rename "FromActivity" to whatever activity you are in. Also try to change .this to .class

Comment: yeah i know, i'm a little confused cause i'm working with fragments to display diferrent tabs in main activity but i tried with both: 
MainActivity gives: error: not an enclosing class: MainActivity. 
And
PlaceholderFragment gives: constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; PlaceholderFragment cannot be converted to String)

Answer (score 0):

I believe following these steps should work.

1. Create a private context variable within the recyclerview adapter class.
2. Change the recyclerview constructor so that it takes in a Context parameter and initializes the private Context variable to the given parameter.
3. Use the newly create context parameter in the Intent.
4. When calling the recyclerview constructor from another class simply pass "this" as the Context parameter.

Code:

1.

```
private Context mContext;
```

2.

```
    public YourRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}
```

3.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YourActivity.class);
```

Comment: but i'm not doing the intent in the adapter and i can't get mContext so why would i need that private context? Or should i write all my listener in the adapter instead?

Comment: Yes, the onClick listener should be in the adapter class.

Comment: I have made an application where, if i remember correctly, I had the same problems. Your onclick should be defined undere the overridden method onBindViewHolder of your adapter class.

Comment: If you can upload your code somewhere I can take a look and try my solution